# Passenger::SecurityException "Line too long"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

After deploying the code in server I got the following error. I am using **phusion passenger** with **nginx**.

The following is my server configuration file.

```
 server{
        listen xx:xx:xx:xxx:8081;
        server_name sideline.com;
        client_max_body_size 500M;
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /home/deploy/domains/sideline/current/public;
        rails_env production;
      }
```

I got the following error.Can any one help me ?

```
An internal error occurred while trying to spawn the application.

Exception type: Passenger::Security Exception

Error message: Line too long
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that, during your application startup, is printing a line that is longer than 1024 bytes (the default line limit). If you get rid of that then that will solve your problem.

See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/rI4BYBu8ke8